# Is the Varna told by Krishna is same as astrological Varna?

Tags: krishna, astrology, varna

[Following](https://asitis.com/4/13.html) statement of Krishna related to Varna

> According to the three modes of material nature and the work ascribed to them, the **four Varnas of human society were created by Me**. And, although I am the creator of this system, you should know that I am yet the non-doer, being unchangeable.

In Vedic astrology, there is Varna. It is solely based on the birth Zodiac sign of the person i.e., on birth details as [follows](http://mokshaastrology.blogspot.in/2009/04/varna-refers-to-caste.html)

> 1. BRAHMIN VARNA : Person whose Birth Rashi is Cancer or Scorpio or
>    Pisces is considered Brahmin by Varna in Hindu Vedic Astrology .
> 2. KSHATRIYA VARNA : Person whose Birth Rashi is Aries or Leo or
>    Sagittarius is considered Kshatriya by Varna in Hindu Vedic Astrology.
> 3. VAISHYA VARNA: Person whose Birth Rashi is Taurus or Virgo or
>    Capricorn is considered Vaishya by Varna in Hindu Vedic Astrology.
> 4. SHUDRA VARNA : Person whose Birth Rashi is Gemini or Libra or
>    Aquarius is considered Shudra by Varna in Hindu Vedic Astrology.

The names of Varnas in both cases are same, my doubt is **whether the Varna system told by Krishna is same as the Varna in astrology or not**?

Note: This question is not a duplicate of another question. Please read both and comment or reopen accordingly.

Comment: haha @hanugm . You are really obsessed with this! Why don't you give this topic a break for a couple of months and then come back to it. You may have some fresh insights. Meanwhile, let's obsess over something else :-D

Comment: @moonstar2001 I am trying well for deviation. Hopefully I may  overcome obsession.

Comment: :-) then we hope to see some interesting Qs from you.

Comment: No, varnas get divided automatically by birth in first half 12000 years(when Rama, Krishna were born).When Krishna left earth around 3000 BC, Kaliyuga ascending cycle started for 12000 years(also called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Aquarius) which contains dominant westerners, science, research like modern mobiles, rockets to reach Satyuga again(by 10000 AD). http://www.dwapara-yuga.org .Ascending yuga doesnot contain strict caste-system, like only 15% world is Hindu,rest are united atheist,Abrahamics & Hindus are divided and puranic, not original Vedic & without guidance of Saptrishis

Comment: One can see varna or nature of person from planets as well, dominant Jupiter, Venus in ascendant or rashi is Brahmin, dominant Sun, Mars is Kshatriya, Dominant Moon, Mercury is Vaishya and dominant Saturn, Rahu is Shudra. Rashis or moon sign can be seen to find internal varna of person but say if someone has Moksha Brahmin rashi with Moon of Cancer, Scorpio or Pisces, but has bad/weak Jupiter and Venus and strong Rahu/Saturn in rashi or ascendant than he/she will show nature of Shudra not Brahmin, therefore all planets must be analyzed to conclude varna of a soul, not moon sign alone.

Comment: @The Destroyer♦

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi ..

Comment: @ManuKumar Technically true but misleading. While Varna is inheritable, it is not how it is defined and the upper three Varnas don't develop until the individual is older (there is a loophole for people who remember their past lives). Think of it how puppies inherit sight, but they are blind when they are born. (Some can be restored sight by treatment)                                                               https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43405/do-migrated-brahmin-person-children-will-become-brahmin-or-non-brahmin/43408#43408

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa varna system and monarchy has failed in the modern age which was done automatically by birth in the Age of Leo( from 14000 BC(last Satyuga) to 2000 BC(last Dwapra)), thats why old monarchy was replaced by democracy and majority people in the current times are spiritually inferior and India is dominated with varnaless and atheist Abrahamics(due to past Mughal and British invasion) who have man-made rules written based on intellect by unenlightened aristocrats of West, not the revealed scriptures like Vedas to past rishis of East.

Comment: @ManuKumar First of all Varna is not a system. Varnas exist regardless of however people organize themselves or believe about themselves.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa everything has 4 varnas or divisions, thats why there are 4 directions, North is Brahmin, East is Kshatriya, South is Vaishya, West is Shudra. Thats why you have 4 fingers in your hand, Index is Brahmin, Middle is Shudra, Ring is Kshatriya and Small finger is Vaishya. These are universal laws based on Trigunas(Satva, Rajas and Tamas) and Nirguna. https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/14 . Four states of consciousness also exist because of 4 varnas/categories https://hridaya-yoga.fr/4-states-of-consciousness/

Comment: @ManuKumar The Varnas are more than just gunas. In the Yaksha Prashna, the Brahmanas and Kshatriyas are told what all the guna traits are.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa The entire universe is projection of Triguna Maya of Atman, hence upanishads say 'Ekam Brahm Dvitya Nasti'. Human Varnas are just divisions of humans by nature for her own simplicity so as to find fit womb for a soul, its nothing like hard God's law and is part of temporary Maya. Real goal of existence was, is and will be only Self-realization which is above Varnas and gunas. Thats why Shiva taught Shankaracharya about the casteless Atman as Chandala in Kashi. https://www.rediff.com/news/special/when-adi-shankaracharya-met-the-chandala/20180629.htm

Comment: @Archit The doubt is simple: Is the varna determined by rashi is same as the varna of jiva mentioned by Krishna.

Answer (score 2):

Swami Vivekananda considered the astrological Varna to be the true Varna.

> Every Hindu knows that astrologers try to fix the caste of every boy
> or girl as soon as he or she is born. That is the real caste — the
> individuality, and Jyotisha (astrology) recognises that. And we can
> only rise by giving it full sway again. This variety does not mean
> inequality, nor any special privilege.

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 4, Writings Prose, A Plan of Work for India (Written to Justice Sir Subrahmanya Iyer from Chicago, 3rd Jan., 1895.)**

Comment: Sir so Nature and Astrology both are considered ??

Comment: My guess is that it is enough to consult only jyotish. The varna obtained from jyotish will map with one's nature.