# Is there any counter example saying astrological varna and geetha varna are different?

Tags: scripture, astrology, varna, varnashrama

Answers to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19422/is-the-varna-told-by-krishna-is-same-as-astrological-varna) says that astrological varna based on  Zodiac sign of a person is same as the varna of a person assigned by Krishna. You can read the referred question for details.

But still I have doubt regarding it and want to find a counterexample if available.

Is there any person from scriptures, whose birth details are available, is treated with varna other than his/her astrological varna?

Comment: One example is Jyotisha of both Rama and Krishna. Both Kshatriyas but their astrological Varna is Brahmin and Vaishya respectively.

Comment: Please post them as an answer.

Comment: @Archit so, it proves that astrological varna and geetha varna are different.

Comment: Although both types of Varnas are by birth, they both are different in nature.

Comment: yes it is different. That’s why we have hereditary kings son king, his son king (capable ones I’m not taking of the others) etc. It is no doubt determined by Guna/ karma and that also logically that Guna is based on what your parents have. So if they’re pure BKSV you’ll also be pure BKSV. But yes migration due to change in Guna is sanctioned by Manu. There are exceptions like Vishvamitra, but then again you see his children becoming Brahmins only (same Guna as Vishvamitra). Every generation there’s no migration. You can’t say I want to be B, my kid will be S his kid will be K

Comment: *Although both types of Varnas are by birth, they both are different in nature* - yes it seems so. Just small example one maybe born a Brahmin but if you have Kshatriya astrological rashi then maybe you have anger or courage to fight. Doesn’t mean you’ll be skilled with weapons, but you’ll have the anger of Kshatriyas or at least strength to stand up against injustice (verbal not necessarily war)

Comment: @Archit Whenever you get time please post an answer, I have a chain of questions to post for which your answer will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [an answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18941/do-any-scriptures-say-that-varna-is-determined-by-rashi/18960#18960), the astrological Varna of a person is determined by checking the Varna of the rashi that the moon is placed in.

I’m giving not one, but two examples of the Varna being different from the astrological Varna. These are the two avatars of Narayana viz. Shri Rama and Shri Krishna. We know that Shri Rama and Krishna were Kshatriyas and actively ruled/ contributed to ruling their respective kingdoms. To however see their astrological Varna, we need to see the placement of moon in their chart. Giving below:-

#### 1. Ramaji

The position of the moon is described in the Valmiki Ramayana, Balakanda 1.18.9:

> ...in conjuction with **Moon is in ascendant of Cancer**, and when day is advancing, Queen Kausalya gave birth to a son...

As per [BPHS 4.10](https://www.astrojyoti.com/bphspage1-2.htm), Karkata is Brahmin Rashi:

> The Rāśi Cancer is pale-red. It resorts to forests and **represents Brahmins..**

Therefore since the moon is placed in Karkata Rashi, Ramaji’s astrological Varna is Brahmin, despite being a Kshatriya by birth as well as later in life when he was crowned king.

#### 2. Shri Krishna:

As per the [birth details](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BFzodiac-sign-of-krishna-and-rama/8538#8538) of Krishna, the moon was placed in Vrisha Rashi.

As per [BPHS 4.8](https://www.astrojyoti.com/bphspage1-2.htm), Vrisha is a Vaishya Rashi:

> Taurus complexion is white ... It represents villages **and businessmen**.

Therefore since the moon is placed in Vrisha Rashi, Shri Krishna’s astrological Varna is Vaishya, despite being a Kshatriya by birth and helping Ugrasena rule the kingdom and actively fighting many battles.

So Ramaji and Krishna are two people from scriptures, whose birth details are available, and are treated with varna other than their astrological varna?

Comment: TIL there is a jyotisha varna !

Comment: @mar you’re back yayyyy!!!! What’s TIL

Comment: Today I Learned. meaning it's something i didn't know until now.

Comment: @mar besides jyotish varna (Rashis and grahas are divided into Varnas. Rashis influence people) I feel all creation should ideally be dividable into four Varnas. Because everything in creation is made of 3 gunas and Varna is based on Guna. The Varnas are divisions for everything be them devatas, jyotisha Rashis, asuras. This is what the Varnas emerging out of Shri Hari mean - all divisions emerge from him. Not humans only. Even asuras You have Shukracharya who’s sattva Guna and Brahmin and planet is also Brahmin. The asura kings are there, you’d be having asura businessmen and service too.